# Either a self-adjoint operator has $n$ eigenvector or not at all

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, orthogonality, adjoint-operators

In the book of *Linear Algebra* by Greub, in chapter 8 Section 1, he argues that

(In summary)

> $E$ is a real finite dimensional inner product space.
>
> If $\phi: E \to E$, is a normal transformation, i.e for $\bar \phi :
>  E\to E$  $$(x, \phi(y)) = (\bar \phi (x), y)\quad \forall x,y \in E,$$
>   and  $$\bar \phi \circ \phi = \phi \circ \bar \phi.$$ Then $\phi$ and
>   $\bar \phi$ have the same eigenvectors, and any two eigenvector of
>   $\phi$ whose eigenvalues are different are orthogonal.

So from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2641401/is-there-any-connection-between-the-fact-that-a-set-of-vectors-are-mutually-orth) we can argue that if $\phi:E \to E$ is a normal transformation and has $n$ eigenvectors whose eigenvalues are different, then those eigenvectors form a orthogonal basis for $E$.

Then in the second section (Self-Adjoint mappings), he first states that

(Direct quote)

> It is the aim of this paragraph to show that a selfadjoint
>   transformation of an n-dimensional inner product space $E$ has $n$
>   eigenvectors which are mutually orthogonal.

[image]

And he shows that $e_1$ is an eigenvector of $\phi$.

**However**, he does not show the existence of such $e_1$, so is it true that either $\phi$ has $n$ eigenvectors which forms a orthogonal basis for $E$, or $\phi$ does not have any eigenvector at all, provided that $\phi$ is self-adjoint. **Or** the existence of $e_1$ is guaranteed in a way that I can't see ?

I mean, as far as I understood, there can never be the case where $\phi$ has $k$ eigenvectors where $k \leq n$, is it the case ?

**Correction:**

Reading the next pages carefully, I have realised that after $e_1$, he constructs the remaining eigenvector in the orthogonal complement of $e_1$,  and applies the same construction, so if the existence of $e_1$ is not guaranteed, none of the others are also not guaranteed, so $\phi$ can have $k \leq n$ eigenvectors.

Comment: If $F$ assumes a minimum, then it must assume a minimum *somewhere*. He defines $e_1$ to be where this happens.

Comment: @Rahul But that minimum does not have to satisfy $F(e_1) \leq F(x)$ for $|x| = 1$.

Comment: What do you think "$F$ assumes a minimum on the sphere" means if not that?

Comment: A continuous function on a compact set attains a minimum. In a linear space where the distance function $d$ is defined by $d(x, y) = \|x - y\|$, compact sets are exactly the closed and bounded subsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just not to add another question to the unanswered questions queue:

As @Rahul and @Anu pointed out in the comments, if we restrict $F$ to the unit sphere, since unit sphere is a closed and bounded subset of $E$, it is compact, hence $F$ assumes a minimum on that subset.Therefore by definition, $\exists e_1$ satisfying $|e_1| = 1$ s.t

$$F(e_1) \leq F(x) \quad \forall x  \quad \text{s.t} \quad |x| = 1.$$

As a result, a self-adjoint mapping of $E$ has to have $n$ eigenvectors (which are mutually orthogonal).